# Django "apps" folder still relevant?

Tags: django

There was somewhere I read couple of years ago (Two scoops of Django 1.4?) suggested having an "apps" folder inside the Django project which hosts all the apps.

```
Repo folder
-- Project root folder
   -- apps
      -- app 1
      -- app 2
   -- settings etc
```

But just had a quick read of "[Two scoops of Django 1.8](https://www.twoscoopspress.com/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-8)" there is no mention of the "apps" folder in the preferred project structure.

```
Repo folder
-- Project root folder
   -- app 1
   -- app 2
   -- settings etc
```

What have I missed? And why did they remove this folder?

Comment: Please update your question with links to these articles so we can review them.

Comment: they are from the books https://www.twoscoopspress.com/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-8

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is just preference and two-scoops is mostly just a style guide.

Answer (score 0):

like @marcusshep said is just preference, anyway if you want to keep your apps inside this folder you can add this line after `BASE_DIR` var  `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'apps'))`. With this you don't have to use apps.app..., is like that folder doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

I personally have gone back and forth on this one.

The new default layout of django is somewhat confusing - having two folders - one for the core software and one for your app.

The thing I have had issue with is by adding your app to the top level of the PYTHONPATH, another package installed from say someplace like PyPi will interfere with yours. For that reason alone I suggest 'namespacing' your apps inside the apps folder. I put 'namespacing' in quotes as by having something like 'myspecialproject' with 'myspecialproject.apps.payments' is a whole lot better than having 'payments' at the top level which will likely get clobbered by some other package.

So yes, I suggest an apps folder inside your project.

Comment: I think you raised a good point about 3rd party packages interfering package names

Comment: Another thing is having an apps folder I can just need to define one logger to point to the "apps" instead of defining logger for every single app.